# Startup PowerShell script, Export-Csv not exporting LogonServer variable

Tags: powershell, logonserver

I have a PC which is continuously logging in, running a script, then logging off and rebooting to repeat the process.

```
$StartTime = Get-Date
...
(other code here, including delay)
...
$LServer = $env:logonserver
$ShutTime = Get-Date

New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
    StartTime = $StartTime
    ShutTime = $ShutTime
    LogonServer = $LServer 
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Apps\DCResults.csv" -Append
```

When I execute the script manually, the file is updated with the correct information i.e. 3 columns of data are filled. But when the script executes on Windows startup, the LogonServer isn't wrriten to the CSV file. That column remains blanks, whereas the other two columns are correct.

EDIT: And actually, it doesn't have to be a .CSV, just a file I can put in Excel to do analysis on. If there's a better way to write to a file...

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183495

Comment: I tried using `SETX $LServer $env:logonserver` which works in PowerShell 1.0 but not in 3.0... Is there are a better syntax for it?

Comment: How/where is this script configured to run automatically?

Comment: It's a set to run on startup through the task scheduler

Comment: Set to run on startup using what account?

Comment: Using a local admin account

Comment: A local admin account's logon server is the local computer.

Comment: hmm.. that's a good point Bill, and probably the right answer. The problem is that I have to use the local admin's elevated rights to run the script on startup. Is there a way to get the logonserver of the currently logged on user? And not the logonserver of the user who executed the script?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart this was essentially the correct answer. I made another task which calls another script using the domain account. How can I award you the bounty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LOGONSERVER environment variable, if set, refers to the computer that logged on the current user (i.e., the user account running your script). For a local account, LOGONSERVER (again, if set) will be the local computer.

Comment: Thanks Bill, this was indeed the problem. Since the task, and therefore the script, was executed as the local admin there was no logonserver variable recorded, even though a domain account was logged in. I had to split up the script and make admin changes through the first one, and record logonserver through the second one (called by a domain account)

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this work instead:

```
$LServer = (gwmi Win32_NtDomain | select DomainControllerName | where DomainControllerName -ne $null ).DomainControllerName[0] -replace '\\'
```

Answer (score 0):

The LogonServer environment variable isn't defined until a user logs in.   If you are running script in the machine startup script, the is no user logged in.   Perhaps if you ran the script as a Login script it would do at you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would configure an autologon user:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324737

Make sure your logon user is a domain user and also a member of the local admins group. Then set the script to run either on startup from the startup folder or in:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Configure the job in the registry to launch via cmd/bat file (just like the scheduled task). The script will run and produce output for any user who logs on who has rights to the folder and file even if you break your autologon user. I would also add a few second delay using the shutdown command so that the reboot part can be easily broken with shutdown -a